# Coffeescript: How to import express module in one line

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

Currently, I have to write

```
app = require 'express'
app()
```

To get the equivalent Javascript:

```
var app;  
app = require('express');
app();
```

How can I do this in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to clear thing up here.

First of all, here is the most *common* way to import express module and create an application:

```coffee
express = require 'express'
app = express()
```

`app` variable here holds a freshly created express application, while `express` variable holds the framework itself.

Now, let's say you don't need express framework here, only an application. In this case you could write:

```coffee
app = do require 'express'
```

And if you don't need a variable holding your application, you could write something like that:

```coffee
do express = require 'express'
```

Though I can't imagine why anyone would want it. Of course, you could chain everything:

```coffee
do express = require 'express'
  .use(express.static('public'))
  .listen(3000)
```

But for me it looks like a mess.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this: `require('express')()`. But the downside to this approach is that you'd lose access to the `app` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
do app = require 'express'
```

Comment: I lose access to the app variable.

Comment: Neat, only it's `app = do require 'express'`

Comment: This works, it compiles to `var app; (app = require('express'))();`

Comment: You'll still have access to the app variable in this answer, but not in the comment by @LeonidBeschastny

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do what you're asking...

For the correct answer (has the **exact** javascript output you want), try one of these:

```
app = require 'express'; do app
app = require 'express'; app()
```

Some other options would be:

```
(app = require 'express') null
do app = require 'express'
app = require 'express'; app null
```

Which result in slightly different Javascript output, but work exactly the same.