# In Node.js ES6 how to import and run module in one line?

Tags: node.js, import, module, es6-promise

Running into an issue with converting to ES6 import I haven't found a solution from searches but traditionally I was able to create a `Promise` as:

```
Promise.all([
  require('../path/to/a')('foo'),
  require('../path/to/b')('bar'),
])
  .then(() => {
    // further code
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e.message)
  })
```

and switching to ES6 I have to write my `Promise` as:

```
import a from '../path/to/a'
import b from '../path/to/b'

Promise.all([
  a('foo'),
  b('bar'),
])
  .then(() => {
    // further code
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e.message)
  })
```

for it to work but if I try to import and run on one line:

```
Promise.all([
  import('../path/to/a')('foo'),
  import('../path/to/b')('bar'),
])
  .then(() => {
    // further code
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e.message)
  })
```

I get:

> ImportCall('../path/to/a') is not a function

### Research

- [react and flow: import Node type and PureComponent in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49089793/react-and-flow-import-node-type-and-purecomponent-in-one-line)
- [Coffeescript: How to import express module in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264688/coffeescript-how-to-import-express-module-in-one-line)
- [How to run a file with imported ES6 modules in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086139/how-to-run-a-file-with-imported-es6-modules-in-node)
- [How to run functions from Command Line in Node module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032287/how-to-run-functions-from-command-line-in-node-module)
- [Run factory function on import in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722077/run-factory-function-on-import-in-typescript)
- [Run function in script from command line (Node JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782693/run-function-in-script-from-command-line-node-js)

Is there a way to import and run a module in one line since that would be the only instance I would need `a()` and `b()`? Note I am not using TypeScript but my search for a solution resulted in many TypeScript Q&As.

Comment: Dynamic import returns a _promise_ of the module. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.

Comment: `import('../path/to/a')` is a dynamic import and it returns a promise itself.  I'd suggest just sticking with the static import `import a from '../path/to/a'` and go with that.  A couple more lines of code, but simpler code and static imports are better than dynamic imports when possible.